# Error: Could not find or load main class

Tags: linux, command-line, java

I executed this command to compile my program

```
java -Xms16m -Xmx64m -cp ".:boilerpipe-1.2.0.jar:lib/nekohtml-1.9.13.jar:lib/xerces-2.9.1.jar:lib/langdetect.jar:lib/jsonic-1.2.8.jar" ExampleProgram.java
```

It reports this error:

> Error: Could not find or load main class ExampleProgram.java

Here is ExampleProgram.java:

```
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.xml.sax.InputSource;

import de.l3s.boilerpipe.document.TextDocument;
import de.l3s.boilerpipe.extractors.ArticleExtractor;
import de.l3s.boilerpipe.sax.BoilerpipeSAXInput;

// Language detect librarys
import com.cybozu.labs.langdetect.*;

import net.arnx.jsonic.JSON;
import net.arnx.jsonic.JSONException;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

import com.sun.net.httpserver.Headers;
import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpExchange;
import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpHandler;
import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer;

public class ExampleProgram {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        EveryDetector evr = new EveryDetector();
        InetSocketAddress addr = new InetSocketAddress("127.0.0.1",8080);
        HttpServer server = HttpServer.create(addr, 0);

        MyHandler hndl = new MyHandler();
        hndl.setDetector(evr);

        MyHandlerExtractContent hnd2 = new MyHandlerExtractContent();
        hnd2.setDetector(evr);

        MyHandlerDetectLanguage hnd3 = new MyHandlerDetectLanguage();
        hnd3.setDetector(evr);

        server.createContext("/",hndl);
        server.createContext("/extractcontent",hnd2);
        server.createContext("/detectlanguage",hnd3);
        server.setExecutor(Executors.newCachedThreadPool());
        server.start();
        System.out.println("Server is listening on port 8080" );
    }
}
```

Source: https://github.com/remdex/boilerpipe-and-language-detect-api-server

How can I solve my problem?

Comment: `java` -> run programs; `javac` -> compile classes.

Comment: Please read ["Hello World!" for Solaris OS and Linux](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/cupojava/unix.html)

Answer (score 0):

For me, in Windows environment this worked  (My class location : C:/MyFolder/MyClass.java) :

```
cd C:/MyFolder/MyClass.java
```

Compiling:

```
C:/MyFolder/MyClass.java> javac MyClass.java
```

Executing:

```
C:/MyFolder/MyClass.java> java -classpath C:/external.jar;. MyClass
```